# Build a number selector dialog with AlertDialog (similar to DatePickerDialog)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-datepicker

With the [DatePickerDialog](https://web.archive.org/web/20170430145756/http://www.androidpeople.com:80/android-datepicker-dialog-example) we can have a fancy interface to set the date as this

[image: DatePickerDialog example]
<sub>(source: [androidpeople.com](http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/datepickerdialog.png))</sub>

I like it but it can only be used to set date so how could I build a "DatePickerDialog-like" [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)?

I mean users could click on the "plus" and "minus" button as well as put in the number with keyboard.

Instead of only being able to select a single date, I'd be able to select three different numbers using the three up/down/scroll controls.

Comment: "I mean users could click on the "plus" and "minus" button as well as put in the figure with keyboard." Explain your question better. It's not clear what you're trying to implement. What is a "figure" and what is the relation between "put with keyboard" and the "figure"? Is that figure a picture? Is it a number? A text? What is it?

Comment: can you please tell me what you would like to do with the dialog, it would help me help you much easier.

Comment: @Samuel Say, I have three baskets and I want users to specify the number of eggs in each of the basket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here you go, check [this](http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5) out. Then, check out [Android Custom Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), which would allow you to make your own custom dialog.

Check out [this](https://github.com/novak/numpicker-demo) project for more information

Answer (score 1):

Make an EditText field that they can edit with a button to the right which says Pick a Date  and pops up a dialog. If the user selects the popup dialog, fill in the EditText with the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom view with a "+" button, an edittext and a "-" button. Make a custom dialog with that view. Read about [Android Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). I hope I helped.